# Inverting color ramp in legend

Tags: dem, elevation, legend, color

I have inverted the color ramp to display land surface elevation, now when I add a legend in print composer it shows the lowest value at the top and the highest at the bottom. See below:

[image]

It is more logical to invert that too (so +10 is at the top and -10 is at the bottom). Is this possible?

Comment: in what software??

Comment: It can be done in ArcGIS, but based on the use of "print composer" I'm guessing you're using QGIS. I think it can be done there as well, but I don't know the exact place to do it. In Arc, it's done in the layer symbology (as opposed to the legend itself). And yes, in my opinion it is more logical to have the higher/positive values at the top.

Comment: @ChrisW Hey Chris, this seems like the right answer, +1. How about posting it to a proper answer so we can upvote?

Comment: @WhiteboxDev Since I don't know the exact dialog location in QGIS, or if there even is one that will do it, I can't really answer the question. Were the question about ArcGIS I could, but sometimes even the little/simple things end up not having corresponding tools/settings/options between the two.

Comment: @ChrisW Ah, you're probably right. I understand.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear about teh software: I am using Qgis 2.4. I have not found a solution for this (yet).